# VB .Net navigate each link and get a specific url

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm having trouble using the web browser in VB .NET to navigate a list of URL's inside a multiline textbox, wait for them for load and get a specific URL (should contain a specific word).

What I have until now:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient


    'Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
    For Each strLine As String In TextBox4.Text.Split(vbCrLf)
        Console.WriteLine("Turning False")
        Console.WriteLine("----")
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(strLine)
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for navigation - " & strLine)
        Console.WriteLine("Navigated")

    Next
    For Each link In links
        TextBox6.Text = TextBox6.Text & link & vbCrLf
    Next
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)(TextBox6.Lines)
    For i As Integer = lines.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If lines(i) = lines(i - 1) Then
            lines.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next
    TextBox6.Lines = lines.ToArray
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    For Each ele As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Links
        'Get whatever text there is in the 'href' attribute
        Dim eletarget As String = ele.GetAttribute("href")
        'Add it to the listbox
        If eletarget.Contains("cfsecure") Then
            links.Add(eletarget)
            'Carry on to the next link
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

First of all, it seems it doesn't wait until fully loaded. After that, I don't get any link from what I asked (don't know if it's related to the first problem I have or any mistake in my code getting the `href` with the word "cfsecure").

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    For Each ele As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Links
        'Get whatever text there is in the 'href' attribute
        Dim eletarget As String = ele.GetAttribute("href")
        'Add it to the listbox
        If eletarget.Contains("cfsecure") Then
            links.Add(eletarget)
            'Carry on to the next link
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

What I'm missing here?